# Fail to run MRKmeans in R for a larger file

Tags: r, hadoop

I'm trying to use MRkmeans in RStudio 0.99.484 and Hadoop-2.3.0 (Windows version). With a file (that contain 755 * 1682 real values and with size of 21 MB) as input data it's done successfully but with the another file (that contain 4832 * 3952 real values and with size of 317 MB) i have some errors and the map-reduce failed, all the MR process and errors is shown bellow.
Is my problem solve If we use larger size in the rmr.options(backend.parameters)? if yes i need a sample code.

```
rmr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'rm -r' instead.
rmr: `/Users/SETUPC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQ9MVgC/file10f06a465c65': No     such file or directory
rmr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'rm -r' instead.
rmr: `/Users/SETUPC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQ9MVgC/file10f0634072aa': No such file or directory
15/10/19 21:49:56 WARN zlib.ZlibFactory: Failed to load/initialize native-    zlib library
15/10/19 21:49:56 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]
packageJobJar: [/C:/tmp/hadoop-Koohi/hadoop-unjar740024213403447693/] []        C:\Users\SETUPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\streamjob2283559356588490466.jar tmpDir=null
15/10/19 21:54:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/10/19 21:54:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/10/19 21:54:12 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/10/19 21:54:13 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
15/10/19 21:54:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1445275456322_0003
15/10/19 21:54:15 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1445275456322_0003
15/10/19 21:54:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job:       http://Hamidreza:8088/proxy/application_1445275456322_0003/
15/10/19 21:54:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1445275456322_0003
15/10/19 21:54:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1445275456322_0003 running in uber mode : false
15/10/19 21:54:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:55:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 1% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:56:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 9% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:56:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 10% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:56:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 11% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:56:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 19% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:56:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 20% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 21% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 26% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 27% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 31% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 39% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 46% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 47% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 66% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:57:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1445275456322_0003_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Container     [pid=container_1445275456322_0003_01_000002,containerID=container_1445275456322_0003_01_000002] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.1 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.3 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1445275456322_0003_01_000002 :
    |- PID CPU_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM(BYTES) WORKING_SET(BYTES)
    |- 176 15 716800 2641920
    |- 6680 17515 979025920 955031552
    |- 5660 0 512000 1769472
    |- 6288 31 1675264 2793472
    |- 6976 11296 363868160 241926144
    |- 2816 0 1736704 2416640

Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137

15/10/19 21:57:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 17% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:58:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 18% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:58:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 22% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:58:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 26% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:58:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 31% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:59:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 47% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:59:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 51% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:59:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 60% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:59:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:59:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :     attempt_1445275456322_0003_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Container [pid=container_1445275456322_0003_01_000004,containerID=container_1445275456322_0003_01_000004] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.2 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.3 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1445275456322_0003_01_000004 :
    |- PID CPU_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM(BYTES) WORKING_SET(BYTES)
    |- 5420 0 716800 2641920
    |- 1420 62 1671168 2785280
    |- 5432 13531 375529472 302137344
    |- 4016 15 507904 1765376
    |- 4204 17125 971837440 951898112
    |- 4208 15 1732608 2404352

Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137

15/10/19 21:59:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 30% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:59:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:59:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 34% reduce 0%
15/10/19 21:59:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
15/10/19 22:00:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 72% reduce 0%
15/10/19 22:00:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 83% reduce 0%
15/10/19 22:00:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/10/19 22:00:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1445275456322_0003_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Container            [pid=container_1445275456322_0003_01_000005,containerID=container_1445275456322_0003_01_000005] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.2 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.3 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1445275456322_0003_01_000005 :
    |- PID CPU_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM(BYTES) WORKING_SET(BYTES)
    |- 5904 15 1732608 2412544
    |- 6872 0 712704 2629632
    |- 4664 14546 971898880 951922688
    |- 3632 78 1667072 2785280
    |- 6092 0 512000 1769472
    |- 6924 13203 371974144 314916864

Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137
15/10/19 22:00:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
15/10/19 22:00:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 17%
15/10/19 22:00:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 76% reduce 17%
15/10/19 22:00:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 83% reduce 17%
15/10/19 22:00:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 17%
15/10/19 22:00:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/10/19 22:00:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1445275456322_0003 failed with    state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1445275456322_0003_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

15/10/19 22:00:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 40
File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=0
    FILE: Number of bytes written=79441152
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
    HDFS: Number of bytes read=63636256
    HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
    HDFS: Number of read operations=5
    HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    HDFS: Number of write operations=0
Job Counters 
    Failed map tasks=4
    Killed map tasks=1
    Killed reduce tasks=1
    Launched map tasks=6
    Launched reduce tasks=1
    Other local map tasks=4
    Data-local map tasks=2
    Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=714657
    Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=39170
    Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=714657
    Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=39170
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=714657
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=39170
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=731808768
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=40110080
Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=78
    Map output records=56
    Map output bytes=79348969
    Map output materialized bytes=79349223
    Input split bytes=93
    Combine input records=0
    Spilled Records=56
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=0
    GC time elapsed (ms)=4670
    CPU time spent (ms)=161251
    Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=373673984
    Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=395513856
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=306708480
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=63636163
15/10/19 22:00:45 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!
Streaming Command Failed!

Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce, combine = combine,     vectorized.reduce,  : 
  hadoop streaming failed with error code 1 In addition: Warning message:
running command '/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/hadoop jar /hadoop-    2.3.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.3.0.jar   -D         "stream.map.input=typedbytes"     -D     "stream.map.output=typedbytes"     -D         "stream.reduce.input=typedbytes"     -D     "stream.reduce.output=typedbytes"         -D     "mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx400M"     -D         "mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx400M"     -files         "/Users/SETUPC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQ9MVgC/rmr-local-    env10f0780c2119,/Users/SETUPC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQ9MVgC/rmr-global-    env10f03b794070,/Users/SETUPC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQ9MVgC/rmr-streaming-    map10f06b4f59ee,/Users/SETUPC~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQ9MVgC/rmr-streaming-reduce10f054f5e9e"     -input     "/tmp/file10f08e55037"     -output         "/tmp/file10f03d086dcc"     -mapper     "Rscript --vanilla ./rmr-streaming-    map10f06b4f59ee"      -reducer     "Rscript --vanilla ./rmr-streaming-    reduce10f054f5e9e"     -inputformat         "org.apache.hadoop.streaming.AutoInputFormat"     -outputformat     "o [... truncated]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the file in the tests directory of the package, it's not really meant for data this wide, nor it's clear to me you should use kmeans when you have as many columns as rows, roughly. If you have k centers, D dimensions and P points, you are fitting kD parameters to P points. If D and P are about the same size, I don't think this is a statistically sound procedure. Even if I am wrong and it is, the data is partitioned by row. There is no scalability on the number of columns. You need to look into a different algorithm. It's not clear what your target data size is. 300MB is not really mapreduce sizes. This memory problem  usually happens because each container allocates all of its memory to a java process and none or little is left for the R process. Please see  help("hadoop.settings").

Comment: Thanks dear Piccolbo, By default for single node hadoop allocate 400MB for container, i'm trying to use a larger size, but i'm new in this field and don't know how can change "rmr.options(backend.parameters)" in order to allocate larger size to container.

Comment: That's why I wrote help("hadoop.settings"). You are not the only one with this problem.